# Implicit Answer to this DE $e^xyy'=e^{-y}+e^{-2x-y}$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$$e^xyy'=e^{-y}+e^{-2x-y}$$
I have to find a solution, ***implict*** solution for the preceding differential equation. The method that I have to use is the separable method.  My attempt went as the following:

> \begin{align}
> e^xy\frac{dy}{dx}&=e^{-y}+e^{-2x-y} \\
> e^xy\frac{dy}{dx}&=e^{-y}+e^{-2x}e^{-y} \\
> ye^x\frac{dy}{dx}&=e^{-y}(1+e^{-2x}) \\
> ye^ydy&=\frac{(1+e^{-2x})}{e^x}dx \\
> ye^ydy&=(e^{-x}+e^{-3x})dx 
> \end{align}
>    $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{ e^y(y-1)=-e^{-x}-\frac{1}{3}e^{-3x}}$$

Is this the implicit way to write the solution, using the separation of variables?

Comment: Looks good for me. Don't forget the constant

Comment: Calling $f(x) = -(e^{-x}+\frac 13e^{-3x})$ we have $y = 1+W(\frac{f(x)}{e})$ with $W$ the Lambert function.

Comment: When you integrate, write a ${}+C$ in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did a good job, for sure.

If, because of the exponentials of $y$, you  start with $y=\log(z)$, you end  with
$$ z' \log (z)=e^{-3 x}+e^{-x}$$ and the general solution of
$$z' \log (z)=f(x)$$ is given by
$$z=\frac{C+\int_1^x f(t)\,dt }{W\left(\frac{C+\int_1^x f(t) \, dt}{e}\right) }=e \exp\left(W\left(\frac{C+\int_1^x f(t) \, dt}{e}\right) \right)$$ For your case, as @Cesareo commented, we let $y=1+W(u)$ we end with
$$ u'=2 \cosh (x)\,e^{-(2 x+1)}=\frac 1 e\left(e^{-x}+e^{-3x} \right)$$